# After blowing a fuse I lost power to two rooms

Tags: electrical, wiring, circuit-breaker

I blew a fuse while accidentally touching a travler wire on a three way switch to the hot wire of the switch beside it. This dual switch contains two 3 way switches.

When I turned back on the breaker I have no power to a couple different rooms. The hot wire to those rooms is no longer hot. Only one brealer was tripped so Im assuming all the rooms are on the same breaker. Could there be a loose wire in the wall after the blow out?

Comment: Could be a few different things.  The easiest to check is that connections are tight.  Quite a few people use the push in connections on outlets instead of the screws and they are known to cause problems.  Turn off the breaker/s and double check there is no power before checking.  If you find the push ins, change them to the screws.

Comment: You may have also tripped a GFI. Check them all.

Comment: The good news is that whatever you knocked loose, fried, melted or exploded is probably in a junction box.  So while it may be time consuming and annoying, it won't be too hard or destructive to find the problem.

Comment: you missed the other tripped breaker

Comment: First thing to do is to turn all breakers off and back on (one at a time).  Sometimes it's not obvious when a breaker is tripped.

Answer (score 1):

> touching a travler wire on a three way switch to the hot wire of the switch beside it

I think there are some mistaken assumptions here.  Traveller wires are "hot" wires too.

So one possibility is that you touched a grounded wire or metal part at the same time.

Another possibility is that those 2 switches are on 2 different circuits and you created a line-to-line short.

Conclusion: You might have 2 circuits to check, and since you've already reset the breakers the next step is to check for loose or damaged connections on those 2 switches.

If both switches still have normal hot on one side, then you'll need to check more of the parts that have "no power".

DON'T move any wires unless the circuits are off.